# How can I connect to XAMPP server? I get error saying Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I'm getting an error saying

> Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\series\databases\index.php on line 10

Here's the little code that I have. I know I am not actually pulling anything from the database but can't go any further until I resolve this issue.

```
<?php 
require 'connect.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT `food`, `calories` FROM `food` ORDER BY `id`";
//$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

while ($query_row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
$food = $query_row('food');  //Fatal error message for this line
$calories = $query_row('calories'); //When I comment out line 10 this gives an error too
}

} else {
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

If you want any more info let me know, I was following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSX72_O7QYY&index=116&list=PL442FA2C127377F07) tutorial that may be out of date.
So yeah, any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query_row['food'];
```

You are using the wrong kind brackets, square brackets access array items.

Comment: thank you, I actually fixed the problem and forgot to come back here, but you're definitely correct!